# VBA Error: Compile error: Expected End Sub

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub Button160_Click()

Function Aspiranti()
On Error GoTo Aspiranti_Err

    With CodeContextObject
        If (.F27 <> "") Then
            TempVars.Add "Perem27", .F27
        Else
            TempVars.Add "Perem27", "*"
        If (.F28 <> "") Then
            TempVars.Add "Perem28", .F28
        Else
            TempVars.Add "Perem28", "*"
        If (.F29 <> "") Then
            TempVars.Add "Perem29", .F29
        Else
            TempVars.Add "Perem29", "*"
               End If
              DoCmd.SetFilter "", "[N ruk] Like [TempVars]![Perem27] And [Spec VAK] Like [TempVars]![Perem28] And Year([Date]) Like [TempVars]![Perem29]", ""
        If (Forms!Asperant.CurrentRecord = 1 And Forms!Asperant.NewRecord = -1) Then
            Beep
            MsgBox "Ne naideno!", vbOKOnly, "Vnimanie!"
            DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
        End If
    End With


Aspiranti_Exit:
    Exit Function

Aspiranti_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Aspiranti_Exit

End Function



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you seem to miss two "End If"

```
With CodeContextObject
    If (.F27 <> "") Then
        TempVars.Add "Perem27", .F27
    Else
        TempVars.Add "Perem27", "*"
    End If '  <<<== missing ?
    If (.F28 <> "") Then
        TempVars.Add "Perem28", .F28
    Else
        TempVars.Add "Perem28", "*"
    End If '  <<<== missing ?
    If (.F29 <> "") Then
        TempVars.Add "Perem29", .F29
    Else
        TempVars.Add "Perem29", "*"
    End If
    DoCmd.SetFilter "", "[N ruk] Like [TempVars]![Perem27] And [Spec VAK] Like [TempVars]![Perem28] And Year([Date]) Like [TempVars]![Perem29]", ""
    If (Forms!Asperant.CurrentRecord = 1 And Forms!Asperant.NewRecord = -1) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "Ne naideno!", vbOKOnly, "Vnimanie!"
        DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Nice catch. The compiler didn't make it that far.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Function` nested inside of a `Sub`.  You can't do that in VBA. If this is supposed to be your Button's click handler, remove the lines

```
Function Aspiranti()
```

and

```
End Function
```

If not, remove the lines

```
Private Sub Button160_Click()
```

and

```
End Sub
```